# Wordpress twenty twelve: i removed the site margins and now the site is too far left

Tags: css, wordpress, width, margins

I removed the margins in my custom css using the code:

```
body .site {
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

The site content is now too far left. Even though my max-width is set to 960 I feel like the content is larger than 960. Is this possible? Does anyone know how to fix this without making the max-width greater than 960?
Here's the site for reference: http://haworthweb.com/wordpress/

Comment: In your site your content is on the left. what else you want to do.state briefly

Comment: I want the width of my content to match the width of my site content area. right now the content bleeds over too far left. I want it to fit perfectly on the content area. let me know if i'm being unclear.